# Why can't I divide (or multiply) a numpy array of arrays by a scalar?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, agent-based-modeling, arrayofarrays

I am working on my first agent-based model (abm) in my life and I have to do operations on an array of arrays. Each agent of my model is an array with numbers that are added by the algorithm when certain conditions are met. Sometimes I have to divide or multiply all arrays by the same number. I saw in numpy array I can do this:

```
vector = np.array([1, 2.1, 3])
```

when I do

```
2 / vector
```

gives me, as expected,  `array([ 2.        ,  0.95238095,  0.66666667])`.

But if I want an array of arrays like for example

```
arrayofarrays = np.array([[1,2,3],[1.1,6],[1]])
```

it has by default `dtype=object` and I guess it is this that doesn't allow me to do

```
2 / arrayofarrays
```

which gives

```
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'list'
```

Also

```
2 / arrayofarrays[0]
```

gives same error.
Instead if you use a single array's value, as

```
2/arrayofarrays[0][1]
```

it works: `1.0`.

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Your arrayofarrays is actually an array of lists. Python lists don't support arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you. So what can I do?

Comment: There's probably a better way, but you could do `arrayofarrays = np.array([np.array(x) for x in [[1,2,3],[1.1,6],[1]]])`

Comment: Numpy is not Python! Python has lists of lists and inner lists are allowed to have each a different length. On the other hand, numpy uses *multi dimensional arrays*. The difference is that the basic type shall be the same for all elements (the numpy *dtype*), and all subarrays of same level shall have the same size. If those conditions are met, and if the dtype is numeric, numpy allows to broadcast operations over the whole array or over inner arrays if dimensions match. As you have a numpy array with *object* dtype it only supports object operations (meaning no operation at all...)

Comment: @SergeBallesta, with object dtype arrays, `numpy` tries to apply the operator to each element.  The results depends on class of the element.  This is done at list comprehension speeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ragged array - an array of lists:

```
In [31]: arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[1.1,6],[1]])
<ipython-input-31-4887f672b831>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[1.1,6],[1]])
In [32]: arr
Out[32]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([1.1, 6]), list([1])], dtype=object)
```

Math on object dtype arrays is performed element by element (at list comprehension speeds).  How it works depends on how the corresponding method works the elements:

```
In [33]: arr *2
Out[33]: 
array([list([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]), list([1.1, 6, 1.1, 6]), list([1, 1])],
      dtype=object)
```

`list*2` is replication operation, not multiplication.

```
In [34]: arr / 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-34-855a165721c4>", line 1, in <module>
    arr / 2
```

Divide is not defined for lists.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

We can apply a simple function to each element with `frompyfunc`:

```
In [38]: np.frompyfunc(lambda x: np.array(x)/2, 1,1)(arr)
Out[38]: 
array([array([0.5, 1. , 1.5]), array([0.55, 3.  ]), array([0.5])],
      dtype=object)
```

This function takes care of the conversion to array as well as the division.

Equivalent list comprehension (just as fast):

```
In [40]: [np.array(x)/2 for x in arr]
Out[40]: [array([0.5, 1. , 1.5]), array([0.55, 3.  ]), array([0.5])]
```

or the pure list version (may be faster)

```
In [41]: [[y/2 for y in x] for x in arr.tolist()]
Out[41]: [[0.5, 1.0, 1.5], [0.55, 3.0], [0.5]]
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. But now I'm really confused: I can't understand why `2 / vector` (my example) worked properly! It seems that if np.array is just an array you can multiply and divide, otherwise not

Comment: `arrayofarrays[0]` is a list.  `arrayofarrays[0][1]` is a number.

Comment: but `vector=np.array([1, 2.1, 3])` and `2/vector` works. Instead `arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[1.1,6],[1]])` and `2/arr` not

Comment: Ok...maybe I'm starting to understand now...
There are things that are actually different but I thought they were the same thing: one can create a list of lists or can create a list of np.array or also a np.array of np.arrays. For example, I did some tests and I see that `test = np.array([ np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([1.1,6]), np.array([1]) ])` is a `dtype=object` but it works properly with `2/test`

Comment: Object dtype arays can hold anything, list, array, number, string, etc.  Math on such an array delegates the action to the elements, at python iteration speeds.  Whether it works is hit-or-miss.